# Slide Edge Loop along Sphere's Edge

Tags: modeling, edges, loop

I am new to Blender. I am taking a class, and in the class the professor was demonstrating how one might start to model a Tie Fighter from Star Wars. So, using the reference images that he showed in class, I decided to see if I could make some headway. So, I start with a sphere (I believe it was a UV-sphere if that makes a difference). I scaled it so that it roughly fit the size of  the reference photo. I'm looking at the reference photo, and I see that the line edge loop at the top of the sphere is not quite close enough to where I would like. So, I try to scale, transform, move, and rotate the edge loop. However, all of those options seem to deform the shape of the sphere.

I want to move the edge loop *along* the shape of the sphere, in order to maintain the sphere shape, but allow me to start matching the image in the reference photo more closely. In the image, the black arrow points to the edge loop, and the red arrow points to where I want the edge loop to move along the sphere.

Now, I understand that I could painstakingly manipulate each line, or vertex. And I thought of creating a new Loop Cut in that position, but I would still need to move all the other current edge loops in to the positions I want them to be. Another thing I have tried is selecting the edge loop moving it, and then scaling it accordingly. This takes about three to four iterations, and I will still have to go back and make sure that each vertex on the edge is in the right spot.

The second image is what I would like to approximate without having to move each line or vertex manually. As I hope you can see that it more closely matches the reference photo.

I am not *currently* trying to get into the programming aspect of Blender.

[image: Photo of UV sphere in Blender and tie fighter reference photo]

[image: Same photo of UV sphere in Blender and tie fighter reference photo, with sphere slightly modified]

Comment: Yes, this works. Now I see the proper terminology to use when searching for answers next time. Thank you.

Comment: Hey no problem, if you want a good, detailed walk-around blender (covering most of the important concepts and terminology) consider looking up and following Andrew Price (The Blender Guru's) donut tutorial. It's very well put together, and has helped many users on this site.

Comment: I appreciate it. Would this question count as a duplicate? If not, you could add your answer.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move an edge along an object without deforming the geometry (too much), with the edge selected, press keyboard shortcut <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to perform an **Edge Slide**:

[image: Slide]